# Git Push to Kudu Service in IIS fails with 500 error

Tags: git, iis, deployment, kudu

I followed the instructions on Kudu's getting started page, and have it up and running locally and was able to create an application.

The issue is that after I add the git url to the project I wish to deploy, and then attempt to push, I get a 500 
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EWyr.png).

In IIS both the service and the application were created, so I'm not sure whats going on.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you able to access the remote you added through browser? i.e. http://localhost:42188/test.git

What do you get if you try `git ls-remote kudu` ?

Comment: When I navigate to localhost:42188/test.git i get a response: "No route registered for '/test.git'". Trying git ls-remote kudu also yields a 500 error.